# Python - utf-8 coding issue

Tags: python, utf-8

My code is:

```
path = "d:\\path\\"
dirs = os.listdir(path)
print u'Files:'
for i in dirs:
    if i[-3:] == 'xls':
        print i

file = raw_input('File: ')
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
```

My filesnames contains letters as "ąń". `workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file)` can't use file from raw_input. Filename is for example "mondayń.xls". I get error: No such file or directory: 'monday\xe4.xls'.`print i` command gives proper filenames. How can I solve it? I am sorry for my english...

P.S. I use python 2.7.10 and Win10

Answer (score 0):

The files are in `D:\\path`, but you're only printing the file names, then opening the name they type. You need to join the name to the path, e.g. with `fullpath = os.path.join(path, file)`, then open that.

Comment: I can open monday.xls file but I can't open mondayń.xls file. Path is ok I suppose.

Comment: Have you tried decoding the path to unicode? Windows can be finicky about encodings when it comes to files, but I believe Python handles `unicode` paths.

Comment: I have tried almost everything... I can't solve it. I can open file using workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(u'fileń.xls') but can't using workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file)